# C++ returning a function from within namespace using std::function

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to return a function using `std::function<type>` but having typing problems... see code:

```
#include "LossFunction.hpp"

LossFunction::LossFunction() {
}

LossFunction::LossFunction(int functionType) {
    this->functionType = functionType;
    this->fun = this->getLossFunction();
}

LossFunction::~LossFunction() {
}

std::function<float(Input,Output)> LossFunction::getLossFunction() {
    switch (this->functionType){
        case 0:
            return this->f1;
            break;
        default:
            return this->f1;
            break;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following errors at compile time:

```
LossFunction.cpp: In member function ‘std::function<float(Input, Output)>           LossFunction::getLossFunction()’:
LossFunction.cpp:18:17: error: cannot convert ‘LossFunction::f1’ from type     ‘float (LossFunction::)(Input, Output)’ to type ‘std::function<float(Input,  Output)>’
return this->f1;
             ^
LossFunction.cpp:21:17: error: cannot convert ‘LossFunction::f1’ from type ‘float (LossFunction::)(Input, Output)’ to type ‘std::function<float(Input, Output)>’
return this->f1;
```

Comment: what is `f1`? you may need `std::bind`

Comment: You need to reference a member function by its qualified name. So `&LossFunction::f1`.

Comment: Show the declaration of `f1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the namespace, it's the distinction between free-standing and member functions. Free-standing functions can be passed to `std::function`'s constructor, but member functions require a `bind` of their first argument, like this:

```
switch (this->functionType){
    case 0:
        return std::bind(&LossFunction::f1, this, _1, _2);
        break;
    default:
        return std::bind(&LossFunction::f1, this, _1, _2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: You need `std::bind(&LossFunction::f1, this, _1, _2);`, assuming a `using namespace std::placeholders;`

Answer (score 1):

It would appear from the error message that `f1` is a member function of `LossFunction`. If it was a standalone function this would work, but a member function needs an object pointer to be called, which can you bind and store in a `std::function` using `std::bind`, or using a lambda like so:

```
return [this](Input in, Output out){ return f1(in, out); };
```

or

```
return std::bind(&LossFunction::f1, this);
```